# CSS margin and width issue

Tags: css

I'm having this issue with my CSS, where the background disappears when it reaches a certain width. I thought the obvious is change the width but it still happens? I'm not too sure how to proceed. Please any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the CSS

```
.box-index {
  clear:both;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 650px;
  min-width: 320px;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
```

[image: Margin issues]

Comment: Please provide HTML code block that contains the background issue as well so we can have a better look into it

Comment: we are not seeing anything in the screenshot provided, do you have a live website so we can check it ourselves? It might be a media query.

Comment: Information provided by is very minimal please post more information like HTML code and what you see when you resize your page.